# DeprecationWarning: `ensureIndex()` is deprecated in Mongoose >= 4.12.0, use `createIndex()` instead

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

hello I have created node application it was working good but from last 2 days I got this error
I have tried to upgrade mongoose but still same error

> DeprecationWarning: `ensureIndex()` is deprecated in Mongoose >= 4.12.0, use `createIndex()` instead

because of this my application has stopped working

here my code to connect with mongodb

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, {useMongoClient: true});
  mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`);
  process.exit(-1); // eslint-disable-line no-process-exit 
 });
```

does anyone have solution of this ,
thanx in advance.

Comment: what you ensureIndex() code looks like?

Comment: A deprecation warning can't be the reason why your app stopped working. It's more likely the use of `useMongoClient`.

Comment: i don't have done coding for ensureIndex() and i don't know why my app not working after this warnning

Comment: @kalpeshR remove `useMongoClient : true` and see if it works again.

Comment: I have this problem too. mongoose has been messing around with changes. I'm experience issues with gridfs stream

Answer (score 10):

I finally solved this quite simply by following the [official mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html) .

Basically there is a flag to pass through the connection options as follows:

```
mongoose.connect(dbconfig.database, {
    useCreateIndex: true
});
```

And this removed the deprecation warning message without having to modify my code any further.

Answer (score 3):

MongoStore causes this notice.Please upgrade connect-mongo

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5692

```
npm i connect-mongo@2.0.0 --save
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add this code block on your connection:

```
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
```

That will fix your problem. I used it like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping`, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection to mongodb successful ...");
  })
  .catch(error =>
    console.log(`there is something wrong on mongoDB connection : ${error}`)
  );

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have upgrade mongoose version to 4.9.9 and now I am not getting any warnning

Answer (score 0):

Following the Mongodb docs. You have to disable autoIndex: false, then call the User createIndexes function. You need to configure your Schema like this.

```
account_type: {
        type: Number,
        default: config.accountType.admin
    },
    account_status: {
        type: Number,
        default: config.accountStatus.unVerified
    },
    socket_id: String,
    picture_url: {
        type: String
    }
},{
    timestamps: true,
    autoIndex: false
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.createIndexes();

// export model
module.exports = User;
```